# Avoiding page breaks on canvas elements

Tags: html, css

I know there are a lot of other posts concerning this exact topic but none of their fixes seem to work for me so I'd appreciate any input. I am trying to make it so there are no page breaks on my canvas elements when I print the page. Below you can see the canvas element breaking:

[image]

```
<div class="avoid-break">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="background-color: red;" width="200" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

```
@media print {
    .avoid-break {
        display: block !important;
        width: 100%;
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
        position: relative !important;
        overflow-x: visible !important;
        page-break-before: auto;
        page-break-after: auto;
    }
}
```

As I understand it, with the current css setup it **should** have 'Generic title' on the first page and the red canvas element on the second. Am I not setting the css properly, or is it possible I need to make changes to its parent? Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Works OK for me on Windows 10 Chrome/Edge/Firefox (except had to put a border on the canvas to see it in the printed version as background color isn't shown). What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and I tried it on Chrome and Firefox. Thanks for testing that though, it might have something to do with css defined else where. I'll continue to look into it and post my results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after looking into it more the problem isn't with the css of the component itself. It was inside a parent div with the class 'row' which uses `display: flex`. As I understand it, flex display is incompatible with page-break-inside. So to fix it I just set the row's display to block and that made the components avoid page breaks.